# What does the keyword 'impression' mean or constitute in web analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to understand what does the keyword 'clicks' mean or constitute in web analytics. I have asked a similar question for clicks since the keywords individually mean 2 different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An impression is nothing more than a view of the tracked entity (i.e. a page or an advert). Basically it only says, that the tracked element was outputed on the screen and that the analytics tool counted the output to be sucessfully done.